# Is it compulsory to use mvp or mvc for web development

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I've done some surface reading on mvc and mvp and they all talk about model, controllers and presenters. My looking up on those things didnt give me enough understanding so I want to know how important using an mvc or mvp is to website development, if it is compulsory to use either of them and lastly their benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not like you can't develop web applications without the use of either of MVC or MVP**. But they both are designing patterns and helps greatly in development an maintenance of your project and code.

At the heart of MVC is Separated Presentation. The idea behind Separated Presentation is to make a clear division between domain objects that model our perception of the real world, and presentation objects that are the GUI elements we see on the screen. Domain objects should be completely self contained and work without reference to the presentation, they should also be able to support multiple presentations, possibly simultaneously.

There are mainly 3 design patterns:

1. MVC (Model View Controller)
2. MVP (Model View Patterns)
3. MVVM (Model View View Model)

---

### MVC (Model View Controller)

The MVC pattern is a UI presentation pattern that focuses on separating the UI (View) from its business layer (Model). The pattern separates responsibilities across three components: the view is responsible for rending UI elements, the controller is responsible for responding to UI actions, and the model is responsible for business behaviors and state management. In most implementation all three components can directly interact with each other and in some implementations the controller is responsible for determining which view to display.

## Model View Presenter(MVP)

The MVP pattern is a UI presentation pattern based on the concepts of the MVC pattern. The pattern separates responsibilities across four components: the view is responsible for rending UI elements, the view interface is used to loosely couple the presenter from its view, the presenter is responsible for interacting between the view/model, and the model is responsible for business behaviors and state management. In some implementations the presenter interacts with a service (controller) layer to retrieve/persist the model. The view interface and service layer are commonly used to make writing unit tests for the presenter and the model easier.

### Key Benefits

Before using any pattern a developers needs to consider the pros and cons of using it. There are a number of key benefits to using either the MVC or MVP pattern (See list below). But, there also a few draw backs to consider. The biggest drawbacks are additional complexity and learning curve. While the patterns may not be appropriate for simple solutions; advance solutions can greatly benefit from using the pattern. I’m my experience a have seen a few solutions eliminate a large amount of complexity but being re-factored to use either pattern.

- **Loose coupling** – The presenter/controller are an intermediary between the UI code and the model. This allows the view and the model to evolve independently of each other.
- **Clear separation of concerns/responsibility**

  UI (Form or Page) – Responsible for rending UI elements

  Presenter/controller – Responsible for reacting to UI events and interacts with the model

  Model – Responsible for business behaviors and state management
  Test Driven – By isolating each major component (UI, Presenter/controller, and model) it is easier to write unit tests. This is especially true when using the MVP pattern which only interacts with the view using an interface.
- **Code Reuse** – By using a separation of concerns/responsible design approach you will increase code reuse. This is especially true when using a full blown domain model and keeping all the business/state management logic where it belongs.
- **Hide Data Access** – Using these patterns forces you to put the data access code where it belongs in a data access layer. There a number of other patterns that typical works with the MVP/MVC pattern for data access. Two of the most common ones are repository and unit of work. (See Martin Fowler – Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture for more details)
- **Flexibility/Adaptable** – By isolating most of your code into the presenter/controller and model components your code base is more adaptable to change. For example consider how much UI and data access technologies have changed over the years and the number of choices we have available today. A properly design solution using MVC or MVP can support multi UI and data access technologies at the same time.

**Key Differences**
So what really are the differences between the MVC and MVP pattern. Actually there are not a whole lot of differences between them. Both patterns focus on separating responsibility across multi components and promote loosely coupling the UI (View) from the business layer (Model).  The major differences are how the pattern is implemented and in some advanced scenarios you need both presenters and controllers.

Here are the key differences between the patterns:

1. MVP Pattern

   - View is more loosely coupled to the model. The presenter is responsible for binding the model to the view.
   - Easier to unit test because interaction with the view is through an interface
   - Usually view to presenter map one to one. Complex views may have multi presenters.
2. MVC Pattern

   - ontroller are based on behaviors and can be shared across views
   - Can be responsible for determining which view to display

> Further More Research on topic to choose best pattern

Further research and also using the term "twisting the triad" will result in a couple of interesting articles to read that always addresses your question.

The most often heard result is this:

1. Do you develop a **web application**? Learn about **MVC**.
2. Do you develop a **winform application**? Learn about **MVP**.
3. Do you develop a **WPF application**? Learn about **MVVM**.

You can follow it on [MVC, MVP and MVM Architectures for web development](https://www.kodefork.com/articles/mvc-mvp-and-mvm-architectures-for-web-development/)

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely not required to use an MVC or MVP framework when writing a web app. People still write apps using nothing more than jQuery. However, many popular frameworks like angular 1, backbone, and knockout do make use of models, views, and/or controllers or some subset of them so it's probably good to know.

As for the benefits, it comes down to maintainability. As applications grow larger they become difficult to modify successfully without some sort of overarching structure to keep things consistent and to ensure good practices are used. Frameworks like angular provide you with this out of the box by using proven and well understood concepts like MVC. Without this you'll eventually have to come up with your own patterns and subsystems, which while doable, can take a lot of time and effort. Either that, or your app buckles under its own weight.

If you're new to development it's difficult to get an appreciation for this without working on a large project and seeing how crazy things get without some structure. I'm not sure it's something you can learn in a vacuum or that you need to concern yourself with too much right now. Eventually it will become painfully obvious to you why it's important.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, it has a lot to do with the ease of maintaining the code as it grows but that's not all.

A framework such as AngularJS allows you to change the way you build sites by applying the MVC methodology. When working with AngularJS is important to shift paradigms  from manipulating the DOM to describing the desired effect and watching it happen.

With MVC each component is kept separate which makes testing them a lot easier. The separation and modular nature of this patterns allows for greater flexibility and allows bigger apps to grow at a faster rate without loosing quality.

A great tutorial on AngularJS can be found at : https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYxzS__5yYQmX2bItSRCqwiQZn5dIL1gt